# Why webpack config has to use path.resolve & path.join

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

It is common seen in webpack configuration that when we need to set the path ,**`path.resolve`** or **`path.join`** are often used , I just want to figure out **why** we have to use them instead of a plain string path e.g. **`'../dist'`**

I partly understand maybe for some purpose , they are used to return the absolute path ,but I think the plain string path is able to function as well.

e.g

```
output: {
filename: '[name].js',
path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js'
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This has nothing to do with webpack, only with the way Node.js handles paths. Paths are not resolved relative to the file path, but relative to the working directory by default. Say we have the following directory structure:

```
project
 ├── a
 |   └── 1.js
 └── b
     └── 2.txt
```

with 1.js containing the following:

```
const filePath = '../b/2.txt';
const content = require('fs').readFileSync(filePath);
console.log(content.toString());
```

then, if we run

```
cd a
node 1.js
```

everything works fine.

But if, instead we execute **from the toplevel directory**, the following:

```
node a/1.js
```

we get an error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\baryl\Desktop\b\2.txt'
```

because the path is now resolved relative to `project` instead of `project/a`. path.resolve solves that.

```
const path = require('path');
const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../b/2.txt');
const content = require('fs').readFileSync(filePath);
console.log(content.toString());
```

now we can safely execute `node a/1.js` from the project directory, and it will work as expected.

Comment: Got it , much appreciated!

Comment: Follow up question, I get the explanation about running a file with "node" command from different locations but in context of webpack, why is this necessary when webpack command can ONLY run from root level. Can we not then make assumption about file paths relative to root of project?

Comment: Webpack does not have to work from root level. For example, one can do `../../node_modules/.bin/webpack` and suddenly it will not work. Also other configuration files might require the Webpack config, and it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: @Bary12 why not just use a template literal to do the string merging with `__dirname` then ? Still the questions remains , why use `path.resolve`?