# Webpack config - why do we use path.resolve for ouput but not entry?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I know why we use path.resolve() to resolve the output path in a webpack.config file.  [That is explained well here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354238/why-webpack-config-has-to-use-path-resolve-path-join)  Why don't we use it for the "entry" though?

Answer (score 3):

> The context is an absolute string to the directory that contains the entry files.

Entry files are resolved relative to the [`context`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/) config property, which is an absolute path.

For the output path ([`output.path`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-path)) webpack needs to know exactly where you want your bundles and output files to be emitted, and as this obviously cannot be the context of your application then you need to specify a new, different absolute path.

> The path.resolve() method resolves a sequence of paths or path segments into an absolute path.

So that is why we use [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) for `output.path` and other config properties that need to be absolute paths, but not entry file paths.